# Using IFrames in Flex 4

Tags: iframe, flex4

We presently have one big swf in flex 4. I would like to embed an IFrame in it. I've found some info on doing it in flex 3 but am hoping for some direction on where to start for flex 4.
Any links would be very helpful.
Thanks

EDIT:
I found this one
http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/
Which I'll be checking out but I am very open to suggestions and/or warnings!

EDIT2: Sorry, I'm dumb... I meant flex 4!

EDIT3:
Seems like the dominant way is to generate an iframe on the page then have the divs make the iframe look like it's part of the flash app.

Comment: What's your motivation for embedding an iframe in your app?  Seems like there could be a way to achieve what you want without having to resort to iframes.

Comment: We would like the flash app to contain a "browsing hub" for other web resources that are used. 
An iframe facilitates this without popping up new tabs and without deactivating menu items in the swf.

The present solution I'm exploring is having javascript adjust divs containing the swf and an iframe as needed. The swf makes a JS call based on a menu-click which then adjusts z-order making it appear as though the swf contains the page in the iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From our research it simply isn't possible to literally embed an iframe into a flex app.

Instead we used some javascript to overlay an iframe (actually, a fancybox) precisely where we want over the swf. This gives the user the illusion that the iframe is embedded.

There are actually a few commercial products that do exactly this as well.